# ListView population from array

Tags: c#, arrays, listview, listviewitem

I'm attempting to fill a `ListView` with items from a 2D array. The array would be something like this:

data:

```
john,doe,jd@test.com,555-123-4567,test
jane,doe,janed@test.com,555-123-4568,test2
test,testing,tt@test.com,555-123-4569,test3
```

etc.

The code I'm using is this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < data.Length; row++)
{
   var item = new ListViewItem();
   item.Text = data[row][0];

   for (int col = 1; col < data[row].Length; col++)
   {
      item.SubItems.Add(data[row][col]);
   }
   ContactsList.Items.Add(item);
}
```

However, when I run the code it ends up pulling just the first column and adding it to the same `ListViewItem` and displaying just that single row. So for the data above it would give me:

```
john jane test
```

and nothing else.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

EDIT 1: here is the ContactList code

```
this.ContactsList = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
...
this.ContactsList.AccessibleDescription = "Contacts List";
this.ContactsList.AccessibleName = "ContactsList";
this.ContactsList.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
   this.FirstName,
   this.LastName,
   this.Email,
   this.PhoneNumber,
   this.Note});
this.ContactsList.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 38);
this.ContactsList.Name = "ContactsList";
this.ContactsList.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(976, 574);
this.ContactsList.TabIndex = 8;
this.ContactsList.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
this.ContactsList.SelectedIndexChanged +=
   new System.EventHandler(this.ContactsList_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

This code was generated by the designer, and being fairly junior in C# I'm not sure if I missed something.

Comment: What code do you use to get `ContactsList` into the ListView?

Comment: I updated my question with the contactsList code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after messing around with it for a bit I found the answer!

The view for the listview needed to be set to detailed.

Sorry for the newbie question, hope this helps someone else.